# Annotate inherited class fields

Tags: inheritance, neo4j, annotations, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm working with Spring Data Neo4j and want to persist an user into the Neo4j DB.
The user (Neo4jUser) extends an user from a generic project that is independent from the Neo4j implementation.

Since every user should have a id, username and email, the generic user looks like this:

```
public class User{
  private Long id;
  private String username;
  private String email;

  //Constructor, Getter, Setter
}
```

Now my problem is, that i want to use the "id" attribute from the generic User as the @GraphId in the specific user.
However, I don't really know how to put annotations on inherited fields.
The Neo4j specification says, if the attribute is named "id" it will be recognized as GraphId without the annotation, but there is still a WARN when i compile.
I'd like to eliminate this warning.

Comment: No need to add the @GraphId annotation since the field is called id. It will be used by SDN as the graph id. What's the warning you want to eliminate?

Comment: The Warn was "WARN ta.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty:  87 - No identity field found for class of type ...". I don't really know why, but it doesn't occur anymore. Since the generic user and the specific user are in different projects, i suspect maven to have produced this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need anotation in the inherited class, since the warning i had was not the fault of neo4j but the fault of maven (probably).
After a mvn update the warning was gone